# Does the view count increase if one account visits twice?

Tags: support, feature-request, views

I am curious about how the view count system actually works. I know that there are similar questions. In similar questions the universally popular answer is turning out to be that it is based on IP address.

However, many a times I see that if I have visited a page the view count increments by 1. Afterward, if I reload the page (in the same login session) it increments *again*. This might also be a coincidence.

If it is based on an IP address system then if someone logs in with the same account in tor browser (which proxies the IP) it would still increase right?

A side suggestion: Shouldn't the amount of views should increment only when one account that has never visited the page earlier, views the page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [How are the number of views in a question calculated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-are-the-number-of-views-in-a-question-calculated) on Meta Stack Exchange:

> There is some sort of a throttling mechanism in action. It saves the
>   information about a question view per visitor like in pairs:
>
> - for anonymous users, it is `IP + QuestionNr`.
> - for authenticated users it is `UserNr + QuestionNr`.
>
> This information is saved in an expiring cache entry for about 15
>   minutes. If a subsequent hit sees the entry is still there it discards
>   the new hit. If it is already gone it allows for a new record.

So, if you visit a question multiple times during a 15-minute period, it counts as one view. However, when for example you visit the question, and then you visit it again after an hour, it counts as two views.

> However, many a times I see that if I have visited a page the view count increments by 1. Afterward, if I reload the page (in the same login session) it increments again. This might also be a coincidence.

[image]

What if someone else visited that question just after you?